Redistribute students from uneven sized groups to relatively even sized groups with two other constraints
I want to assign students from the 2024 cohort (n=105, female=61, male=44) into groups for 2025. The distribution I am hoping to achieve (in order of importance):

no more than two students from a 2024 group can carry over to the same 2025 group
2025 groups must be as gender-balanced as possible, so something like 7 or 8 females and 5 or 6 males per group
2025 group sizes must be as even as possible, ideally 7 x 13 and 1 x 14
where possible, allocation should be random

Given that a solution may not be possible if criteria 1-3 are strictly adhered to, there is some flexibility regarding group size and randomness.
The sizes and gender balance for the 2024 groups are relatively uneven:
table(df[, c("Gender", "g2024")])
#         g2024
# Gender   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#   Female 7 7 7 7 9 7 9 8
#   Male   4 4 8 6 5 7 4 6

table(df[, "g2024"])
# g2024
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
# 11 11 15 13 14 14 13 14

Using predetermined values, a rudimentary example of what I am trying to achieve:
# Create random vector with group ids for females per group, assign to g2025
set.seed(42)
grp_fem <- as.character(rep(1:8, sample(c(rep(7, 3), rep(8, 5)), 8)))

df$g2025 <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {  
  if (df$Gender[i] == "Female") {
    x <- sample(grp_fem, 1)
    grp_fem <<- grp_fem[-match(x, grp_fem)]
    return(x)
  } else { 
    return(NA)    
  }
}))

# Get males per group, change one group length so y sums to male count
x <- as.integer(table(df$g2025))
y <- 13 - x
z <- sample(which(y == 5), 1)
y[z] <- 6

# Create vector with group ids for males per group, assign to g2025
grp_mal <- as.character(rep(1:8, rep(y)))

df$g2025 <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  if (df$Gender[i] == "Male") {
    x <- sample(grp_mal, 1)
    grp_mal <<- grp_mal[-match(x, grp_mal)]
    return(x)   
  } else {
    return(df$g2025[i])  
  }
}))

# Gender distribution per group
table(df[, c("Gender", "g2025")])
#         g2025
# Gender   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#   Female 7 8 8 8 7 8 7 8
#   Male   6 5 5 5 6 6 6 5

# Number of students carried from g2024 to g2025 groups
table(df[, c("g2024", "g2025")])
#      g2025
# g2024 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#     1 0 2 1 2 1 2 3 0
#     2 1 3 2 2 0 0 1 2
#     3 2 2 1 2 3 2 1 2
#     4 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2
#     5 2 1 4 0 2 3 1 1
#     6 5 3 1 2 0 0 2 1
#     7 1 1 0 1 2 2 1 5
#     8 1 0 2 3 3 3 2 0

Predetermined group sizes and gender distribution values are obviously not ideal, and it does not account for how many students from a given 2024 group end up in the same 2025 group.
I tried using a matrix with a mostly random distribution of group-to-group allocation:
m <- structure(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
                 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
                 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
                 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), dim = c(8L, 8L))

rowSums(m)
# [1] 11 11 15 13 14 14 13 14
colSums(m)
# [1] 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 14

but this also required predefined colSums() values and some manual manipulation. I suspect the lpSolve package might be able to handle something like this, but I was not able to understand how to use it.
Data:
df <- structure(list(Student = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", 
"63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
"74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", 
"85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", 
"96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105"
), Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Female"), g2024 = c("4", "3", "3", "8", "2", "8", "4", "5", 
"8", "7", "2", "4", "4", "6", "6", "5", "1", "3", "7", "2", "6", 
"8", "2", "8", "1", "5", "8", "3", "3", "1", "5", "5", "1", "3", 
"8", "6", "1", "7", "5", "5", "1", "7", "4", "7", "5", "4", "8", 
"6", "3", "1", "7", "8", "7", "7", "2", "4", "8", "3", "7", "1", 
"6", "3", "6", "8", "2", "3", "3", "5", "7", "2", "2", "2", "8", 
"6", "1", "1", "4", "1", "6", "8", "2", "6", "5", "2", "5", "3", 
"3", "7", "3", "4", "3", "4", "7", "4", "6", "8", "4", "6", "6", 
"6", "5", "4", "5", "5", "7"), g2025 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -105L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


I don't think lpSolve would work here because it requires a linear function, whereas I think this will have to be non-linear. This table of optimization packages from Data Science for Production and Logistics doesn't show any R packages that can deal with non-linear, discrete optimization problems, and to be honest the more comprehensive list linked there scares me.
However, this strikes me as a perfect application for simulated annealing, so I implemented the simple simulated annealing algorithm given on the Wikipedia page.
anneal <- function(
    # initial state
    s0, 
    # energy function
    E, 
    # neighborhood function
    neighbor, 
    # cooling schedule
    temperature = function(r) Tmax * r ^ Tpwr, 
    # acceptance probability function
    #   default from Kirkpatrick et al. (1983)
    #   https://doi.org/10.1126%2Fscience.220.4598.671
    P = function(Eo, En, t) if (En < Eo) 1 else exp(-(En-Eo)/t), 
    # no. of iterations
    kmax = 1000,
    # initial temp. and shape of curve; not used if temperature is specified
    Tmax = 1, Tpwr = 1
  ) {
  
  # line-for-line pseudocode from Wikipedia, translated to R
  s <- s0
  for(k in 1:kmax) {
    t <- temperature(1-(k-1)/kmax)
    sn <- neighbor(s)
    if (P(E(s), E(sn), t) >= runif(1)) 
      s <- sn
  }
  return(s)
}

Easier than figuring out how to use a new package IMO, and we would still need to do this next part anyways of defining the optimization function:
library(dplyr)
# Energy function (i.e. cost function i.e. optimization function)
cost <- function(s) {
  df2 <- df
  df2$g2025 <- s
  # "1. no more than two students from a 2024 group can carry over to the same
  #   2025 group"
  # Cost: 0 if 2 or fewer students from same group, 1 if 3, increases by square
  #   beyond 3
  cost1 <- sum(
    pmax(0, summarize(df2, nsame = max(table(g2024)), .by = g2025)$nsame-2)^2
  )
  # "2. 2025 groups must be as gender-balanced as possible, so something like 7 
  #   or 8 females and 5 or 6 males per group"
  # Cost: Square of difference between group gender proportion and overall
  #   gender proportion
  cost2 <- sum((
    summarize(df2, pfem = mean(Gender == "Female"), .by = g2025)$pfem -
    mean(df2$Gender == "Female")
  )^2)
  # return linear combination of cost 1 and cost 2
  # weights can be tuned to improve results
  return(1 * cost1 + 10 * cost2)
}

# neighborhood function
# swaps to students at random
# preserves equal group sizes
neighbor.swap <- function(s) {
  swap <- sample(1:length(s), 2)
  s[`[<-`(1:length(s), swap, rev(swap))]
}

# Initial state, satisfies requirement #4 of randomness
s0 <- rep_len(unique(df$g2024), length.out = nrow(df)) |>
  sample(nrow(df))

Then we can run the simulated annealing (with parameters found through trial-and-error):
# run simulated annealing
set.seed(8675309)
df$g2025 <- anneal(
  s0 = s0,
  E = cost,
  neighbor = neighbor.swap,
  kmax = 2500,
  Tmax = 2,
  Tpwr = 2
)

And check out how it did:
table(df[, c("g2024", "g2025")])

#>      g2025
#> g2024 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#>     1 0 1 2 1 1 2 2 2
#>     2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
#>     3 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2
#>     4 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2
#>     5 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2
#>     6 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1
#>     7 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1
#>     8 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1

table(df[, c("Gender", "g2025")])

#>         g2025
#> Gender   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#>   Female 8 8 7 8 8 8 7 7
#>   Male   5 5 6 6 5 5 6 6

table(df[, c("g2025")])

#> g2025
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
#> 13 13 13 14 13 13 13 13 



From these tables, we can see that criteria 1-3, respectively, are satisfied. Technically this approach gives higher priority to #3 than #1 or #2, but since all are satisfied it doesn't matter for these data, and it'd be simple to change that if it did matter. As for criterion #4, the groupings are random insofar as the initial guess was random and the neighborhood walk was random (though guided).

And as a footnote, here's a version of anneal with an option to print diagnostic information:
anneal <- function(
    s0, 
    E, 
    neighbor, 
    temperature = function(r) Tmax * r ^ Tpwr, 
    P = function(Eo, En, t) if (En < Eo) 1 else exp(-(En-Eo)/t), 
    kmax = 1000,
    Tmax = 1,
    Tpwr = 1,
    verbose = TRUE
  ) {
  
  s <- s0
  if (verbose) Es <- numeric(kmax)
  for(k in 1:kmax) {
    t <- temperature(1-(k-1)/kmax)
    sn <- neighbor(s)
    if (verbose) Es[k] <- E(s)
    if (verbose) message(
      "Iteration: ", k, "\n",
      "Temperature: ", t, "\n",
      "Energy: ", E(s), "\n"
    )
    if (P(E(s), E(sn), t) >= runif(1)) s <- sn
  }
  
  if (verbose) plot(
    x = 1:kmax, 
    y = Es, 
    type = "l",
    xlab = "Iteration",
    ylab = "Energy",
    main = "Convergence plot"
  )
  
  return(s)
}


